# Import npm package to nuxt appliction

Tags: nuxt.js

For SEO Reasons i had to rebuild my vuejs app with Nuxt.

How can you import npm packages in nuxt app?

like in vue.js you simply add the code below to APP.vue

```
import InfiniteLoading from 'vue-infinite-loading'
vue.use(InfiniteLoading)
```

Comment: make a plugin and include it in the nuxt.config.js

Answer (score 1):

create new file in plugin folder `infinite-loading.js`

```
import vue from "vue"
import InfiniteLoading from 'vue-infinite-loading'
vue.use(InfiniteLoading)
```

in `nuxt.config.js` include your file name in plugin array

```
  plugins: [
    '@/plugins/infinite-loading',
  ],
```

then restart the serve