# What is the right way to import vue package in nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, npm-package

I try to import [this](https://github.com/lekhang2512/vue-upload-multiple-image) package into my nuxt project.
All my coding experiments can be found [here](https://github.com/BEEugene/some-nuxt-demo-proj). I will refer to different branches.

There are several ways to do so:

1. Just import it right in the page like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60964218/8668595) ([master](https://github.com/BEEugene/some-nuxt-demo-proj/blob/9fd56b25c76d1368bd095f1e195ebd294d040799/pages/test/index.vue#L22) branch)

This way worked well. You can go to the uploading page via a button on a home page.

[image: home page example]

Until you manually refresh the page [image: refresh page]

Then you will get this error `SyntaxError Cannot use import statement outside a module`

[image: error message]

The same error happens when you try to build it.

2. Import it via [plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63334174/8668595) (like in [plugin-use](https://github.com/BEEugene/some-nuxt-demo-proj/blob/5ba4b4ac417b21b1a04336285751266e21b1c759/nuxt.config.js#L21) branch with or without vendor option in build)

I've got the same error.

3. Import it via plugins with some [options](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-plugins) (like in [plugin-options](https://github.com/BEEugene/some-nuxt-demo-proj/blob/625825c5533b3834ecfb57d1e81085e7a67ee7e8/nuxt.config.js#L21) branch)

Then the package loads only when you refresh the page and only in dev mode.

If you will go to that button on a home page (referenced before) - there will be an empty page.

4. Import it through modules (like in [modules](https://github.com/BEEugene/some-nuxt-demo-proj/blob/005a0346bfbc19ea3c43677fc3f51590dbbda402/nuxt.config.js#L32) branch).

Then the nuxt cannot load at all, this error happens `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Could you comment on each method and why it doesn't work?
How to import it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final answer is following (I've looked up the projects which use this package).

[image: used by]

There was a [project](https://github.com/Dzale/nuxt-to-show) which run on Nuxt.

These are changes which you should add to @tamzid-oronno 's answer

```
//vue-upload-multiple-image.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueLazyload from 'vue-lazyload'
import VueUploadMultipleImage from 'vue-upload-multiple-image'

Vue.use(VueLazyload) // this is from the package installation guide
Vue.component('VueUploadMultipleImage', VueUploadMultipleImage)
```

And list it in plugins the same way.

```
//nuxt.config.js
plugins: [ 
      { src: '~plugins/vue-upload-multiple-image', ssr: false }
]
```

Thus you will be able to use the package without importing it in pages as tags. This was implemented in [plugin_plus_lazy](https://github.com/BEEugene/some-nuxt-demo-proj/tree/plugin_plus_lazy) branch.

Both tags will work vue-upload-multiple-image and VueUploadMultipleImage.

```
//your-index-file.vue
<template>
  <div id="my-strictly-unique-vue-upload-multiple-image" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <vue-upload-multiple-image
      @upload-success="uploadImageSuccess"
      @before-remove="beforeRemove"
      @edit-image="editImage"
      :data-images="images"
      idUpload="myIdUpload"
      editUpload="myIdEdit"
      dragText = "Drag an image here"
      browseText = "(or click here to browse)"
      primaryText = "Default Image"
      markIsPrimaryText = "Set as default image"
      popupText = "This image will be set as default"
      dropText = "Drag and drop"
      accept = image/jpeg,image/png,image/jpg,image/tif,image/tiff
    ></vue-upload-multiple-image>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "AppUpload",
  data(){
    return{
      file:"",
      images: []
    }
  },
  methods:{

    uploadImageSuccess(formData, index, fileList) {    },
    beforeRemove (index, done, fileList) {    },
    editImage (formData, index, fileList) {   },
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

To create a static version and test it on your local machine do the following:

```
$ npm run generate
# test the project
$ npm install http-server
$ cd dist
$ http-server -p 3000
```

I still have a question - why does it work? :)

Comment: You save my day. Thanks. This is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use it as plugin.

1. In the plugins folder, make a file named vue-upload-multiple-image.js

   ```
   //vue-upload-multiple-image.js

   import Vue from 'vue'
   import {VueUploadMultiple} from 'vue-upload-multiple-image'
   Vue.use(VueUploadMultiple)
   ```
2. List it under plugins block on nuxt.config.js

   ```
   //nuxt.config.js

   plugins: [ 
         { src: '~plugins/vue-upload-multiple-image', ssr: false }
   ]
   ```

Thus you will be able to use the package on any component of your project

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, this didn't work. It resulted in case 3 described in question (a blank page). But I was able to import the package. I described in my answer. If you can extend it and explain why does it work that way - it will be wonderful!